# Delaying Ext Ajax request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

I am using ExtJS with Rails 3.0.6

I have a button, whose onClick event results into insertion of record in 2 tables simultaneously, via 2 controllers ( and 1 store). But there is some uncertainity observed as to which event is executed first.

for Table1, records are inserted using **"Store.save()"**

Table2 - **Ext.ajax.request()**

Is there a way to delay the insertion of records in Table 2, untill all the records are inserted in Table1, because Table2 needs to get updated depending upon values of Table1.

I tried using **"afterCommit()"** event but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Controller code would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function()
            {
              //your code that u want to execute after completion of ajax request
            });
```